# WPF animate side menu three sizes / states

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i need to create a menu in WPF that have three sizes. Visible (text and icon), small (Icon) and collapsed. My idea was to take a grid with two columns, one for menu (left) and one for my main Content (right). Then i wanted to animate the left column width by button click (should look like expander). Now is my Problem to animate the column width to Auto for the visible state. Has anybody an idea or a sample to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want to animate Grid.Width property. Grid.Width and Grid.Height properties are of type [GridLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.gridlength(v=vs.110).aspx), and WPF has no standard animation class for GridLength type. "Auto" - is just a special value of GridLength. So you probably need to write your own GridLengthAnimation class. See [DoubleAnimation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation(v=vs.100).aspx) class as example. Here couple of links to help your: 
https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/08/20/gridlength-animation/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18379/WPF-Tutorial-Part-Writing-a-custom-animation-cla

**UPD:**
If you want animate To Auto value, you must know final size of your left column, because animation operates with range of values beween From and To values. So you must decide - how you will draw intermediate values? As variant - always start showing your grid with expanded menu and left column in Auto state, and then, after starting animation (collapsing column) - takes ActualWidth of Grid and use it as From value, and, after starting animation again (expanding column)- use this saved ActualWidth as To value, and finally, at completing reversed animation, return Auto from GetCurrentValue.

Comment: Yes, I want to animate Grid.Width property. I already found the way of custom animation and tried it. but I did not found a way to handle GridLength.Auto an "To" value.